# How to add new 'authorized redirect uris' and 'Authorized JavaScript origins' using PHP?

Tags: credentials, google-api-client, google-signin

I have project with login function via *google's account*. To do this, I had to *created Credentials* for my application. After that, I add new *Authorized JavaScript origins* is my domain name, and *authorized redirect uris* is my url to function login with google, all of them is in Client ID for Web application tab.

- When I setup my application in new domain, I have to type new domain and new uri into google console.
- Now, I make my application setup in a new domain automatically, everything is ok. But I can't use login function via google, because I don't register new domain in google console. So I want to add new 'authorized redirect uris' and 'Authorized JavaScript origins' automatically when I setup my application.

My application is written by PHP. Anyone, who can help me? THANKS?